# Oracle update query using condition from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to update a column in a table based on the below select statement.  The column I'm updating is not join condition and is a different value.

```
SELECT * 
FROM TRANS DT, RECOVER RT
WHERE DT.SERIAL_NUMBER =RT.SERIAL_NUMBER
AND DT.DATE >= TO_DATE('07/14/2016','mm/dd/yyyy')
```

I've tried the following and get errors.  Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
UPDATE TRANS
SET CODE = SUCCESS
WHERE (SELECT * 
       FROM TRANS DT, RECOVER RT
       WHERE DT.SERIAL_NUMBER = RT.SERIAL_NUMBER
         AND DT.DATE >= TO_DATE('07/14/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Is SUCCESS a column of `RECOVER` or a string?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: SUCCESS is the value/txt I want the column Code to be updated to for all of the rows that my query returns

Comment: to add Code is a column in trans

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer.

Comment: sorry all.  I figured this out and forgot to update.  Thank you all regardless

Answer (score 1):

Since `SUCCESS` is a string try with Exists:

```
UPDATE TRANS
SET CODE = 'SUCCESS'
WHERE exists (SELECT 1
                FROM  RECOVER RT
               WHERE TRANS.SERIAL_NUMBER = RT.SERIAL_NUMBER
                 AND TRANS.DATE >= TO_DATE('07/14/2016','mm/dd/yyyy');
```